# Jackson object mapper returns 0 for integer and null for string

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I have a list of structures that I will be getting it from restEndpoint and I have to map it to list of Java Object. But in this project I had just given a string in json format as input. I am always getting null when I try to fetch the string data in my object and 0 when I fetch integer.

I think the objectMapper is not able to map the string json to object. But there is no error that I'm getting.

results = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference>() {}); None worked. Maybe some configuration or version issue?>

My Object

```
public class myObject {

    @JsonProperty("userID")
    private int userID;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("body")
    private String body;
    @JsonCreator
    public myObject() {
    }
    @JsonProperty("userID")
    public int getUserId() {
        return userID;
    }
    @JsonProperty("userID")
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userID = userId;
    }
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    @JsonProperty("title")
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    @JsonProperty("body")
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
    @JsonProperty("body")
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
```

My mapper function is something like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
          mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
 try {
            //List<myObject> mstCodes = null;
            String json = "[{\"userID\":1,\"id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"IT\",\"body\":\"123234\"},{\"userID\":0,\"id\":\"2\",\"title\":\"Accounting\",\"body\":\"adsfnsdf\"}]";
            List<myObject> mstCodes = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, myObject.class));
            System.out.println(mstCodes.size());
            System.out.println(mstCodes.get(0));
            System.out.println(mstCodes.get(0).getUserId());
            System.out.println(mstCodes.get(0).getBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed serializing response" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

The outputs that I receive for above print statements are:

```
2
com.example.varun.testProject$myObject@4e7dc304
0
null
```

It might be a simple mistake, but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)* literally says - with no setters and getters....

Comment: You should have applied @JsonProperty only to the fields (remove them from getters/setters) and then use defaut `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();` without visibility rules - it should work fine in your case,

Comment: It almost certainly doesn't "return" them but rather simply isn't deserializing anything into them (leaving them in their default state). Eliminate *every single Jackson annotation* from your class and *every single custom configuration* from your mapper and see if it works as expected. You're doing a whole lot of manual configuration that you don't understand yet, all of it unnecessary because Jackson is tuned to work well by default.

Comment: That was the think I did before obviously. I just wrote ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); without any visibility rules and no JsonProperty. It's not working even with removing everything

Comment: removed all properties one by one. Nothing is working. Just keeping  @JsonCreator
        public myObject() {
        } in constructor and @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class testProject {

Comment: I think there is a problem somewhere else, because even by copy/pasting your exact code (just wrapped in a `main` method) I get the expected result. It is running on Java 8, Jackson Databind 2.9.9.3 (not the latest which is 2.10.3). I noticed the `setVisibilityChecker` method is deprecated but the whole piece of code works.

Answer (score 3):

I just simplified your `myObject` class with [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) for demo purpose.
I also just used a simple `ObjectMapper`.
The trick is to use a `TypeReference` which takes a generic type that can be whatever you need (`List<MyObject>` in your case).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("userID")
    private int userID;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("body")
    private String body;

}

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String json = "[{\"userID\":1,\"id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"IT\",\"body\":\"123234\"},{\"userID\":0,\"id\":\"2\",\"title\":\"Accounting\",\"body\":\"adsfnsdf\"}]";
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            final List<MyObject> results = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>() {});
            System.out.println(results.size());
            System.out.println(results.get(0).getUserID());
            System.out.println(results.get(0).getBody());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
2
1
123234
```

EDIT:
To solve the error `No suitable constructor found for type`, here is how your object should look like without Lombok (but it does the same). You must provide an empty constructor and an all args constructor.

```
@Getter
class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("userID")
    private int userID;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty("body")
    private String body;

    public MyObject() {}

    public MyObject(int userID, int id, String title, String body) {}

}
```

Comment: I tried with that previously, but it isn't working. Still getting these results. 2
0
null. Is it some version issue?

Comment: If you tried that and it didn't work, I think the issue would be with your `myObject` class itself. Try to make it very simple. As suggested by others, only keep the `@JsonProperty` annotations on the class properties. Remove annotations on the constructor, getters and setters.

Comment: If I remove @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) I get this error --->   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "userId" (class com.example.varun.testProject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])      and if I remove this from constructor @JsonCreatorI get this error Failed serializing responseNo suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.example.varun.testProject$MyObject]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

Comment: You should really edit your question with your actual code because it will be hard to help you if you share a redacted version. The error `Unrecognized field "userId"` is because you receive a `userId` property from in JSON from the service you call. But in your code you only mapped the `userID` property (see difference in case).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the default object mapper below:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

and then use this objectMapper for achieving what you desire.

For a single object, you can use following code snippet for mapping JSON to your object with JACKSON.

```
YourObject yourObject = (YourObject) mapper.readValue(json, YourObject.class);
```

Finally, because of that you have asked: The ObjectMapper is able to map the JSON to Objects with JACKSON with no errors.

Comment: I need it for list of objects. Not just for a single object.

Comment: You can traverse your list one by one and add each mapped object to your list each time.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked using plain `ObjectMapper` without redundant annotations on `MyObject` (Jackson 2.10):

```java
public class MyObject {

    private int userID;
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public int  getUserID()           { return userID; }
    public void setUserID(int userID) { this.userID = userID; }

    public int  getId()       { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getTitle()             { return title; }
    public void   setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

    public String getBody()            { return body; }
    public void   setBody(String body) { this.body = body; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject [userID=" + userID + ", id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", body=" + body + "]";
    }
}

public class MyObjectJsonTest {
    public static void main(String...args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "[{\"userID\":1,\"id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"IT\",\"body\":\"123234\"},{\"userID\":0,\"id\":\"2\",\"title\":\"Accounting\",\"body\":\"adsfnsdf\"}]";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<MyObject> list = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[MyObject [userID=1, id=1, title=IT, body=123234], MyObject [userID=0, id=2, title=Accounting, body=adsfnsdf]]
```